# Adding a clear button with HTML and JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, button

I can't figure out why this won't work! My clear button does *nothing*. Here is my entire form/calculator. I need the "clear" button just to get rid of the text in the "feet" and "meters" fields.

I'm working on a class project.

```
<body>
<form name="myForm">

<table  border = "0" width = 300px>
<tr>
  <td> 
    Feet:
  </td>
  <td>
    <input type="text" id="feet">
  </td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td> 
    Meters:
  </td>
  <td>
    <input type="text" id="meters">
</tr>
</table>
</form>
</body>

<p>
<button onClick="calculate()">Convert</button>
<button onClick="clear()">Clear</button>
<p>

<script>

function calculate()
{
  var feet = document.getElementById("feet").value;
  var meters = document.getElementById("meters").value;
  var final;

  if (feet == "" && meters == "")
  {
    alert("Try Again");
    return;
  }
  else if (!(feet == "") && !(meters == ""))
  {
    alert("Try Again");
    return;
  }
  else if (feet == "")
  {
    final = (meters*(3.28084));
    //Display!
    final = final.toFixed(2);
    document.getElementById("feet").value = final;

  }
  else if (meters == "")
  {
    final = (feet*(.3048));
    //Display!
    final = final.toFixed(2);
    document.getElementById("meters").value = final;
  }
} 

//****************************************************************
function clear()
{   
   document.getElementById("myForm").reset();
}

</script>
```

Comment: You have stuff outside of your <body>

Comment: Why aren't you just using a reset button? `<button type="reset">Clear</button>` And why aren't you using a submit button?

Comment: In other words, you're bleeding paragraphs and buttons

Answer (score 4):

The actual problem is that you are using this

```
document.getElementById("myForm").reset();
```

but your form has no ID, so you would add the ID

```
<form name="myForm" id="myForm">
```

[**Working demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/sGBtf/)

That will work for you, but if you want to fix your code read on.

You have a few errors. Your form needs an id because you're using `getElementById`
There's no need to use a button to submit javascript that does what a button can do.
You have `</body>` then more HTML.
There's a missing `</td>`
`<table  border = "0" width = 300px>` is not correct syntax (and you should really use the style attribute or a CSS file)

Also you can use a submit button and bind the function to the action of the form being submitted, which I've done here.

```
<body>
<form name="myForm" id="myForm">
    <table  border = "0" width = "300">
        <tr>
            <td>Feet:</td>
            <td><input type="text" id="feet"></td></tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Meters:</td>
            <td><input type="text" id="meters"></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
    <button type="submit">Convert</button>
    <button type="reset">Clear</button>
</form>

<script>

document.getElementById("myForm").onsubmit=function(){
    calculate();
    return false;
};

function calculate()
{
  var feet = document.getElementById("feet").value;
  var meters = document.getElementById("meters").value;
  var final;

  if (feet == "" && meters == "")
  {
    alert("Try Again");
    return;
  }
  else if (!(feet == "") && !(meters == ""))
  {
    alert("Try Again");
    return;
  }
  else if (feet == "")
  {
    final = (meters*(3.28084));
    //Display!
    final = final.toFixed(2);
    document.getElementById("feet").value = final;

  }
  else if (meters == "")
  {
    final = (feet*(.3048));
    //Display!
    final = final.toFixed(2);
    document.getElementById("meters").value = final;
  }
} 

</script>
</body>
```

Comment: Closing TD tags are optional, though this seems to have been omitted from HTML5.

Comment: @RobG good point, but OP used them sometimes and sometimes not, so that suggests they're missing

Answer (score 3):

```
<button type="reset" value="Reset">
```

Why do you have to use JS to accomplish this outside of the JS attached to the clear "button"?  I would stick to HTML and just use a simple form reset.

Or, try this here:
http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/tryit.asp?filename=tryjsref_form_reset

Comment: Point taken, was just trying to emphasize the simplicity of a form clear.

Answer (score 0):

change the `<form name="myForm">` to `<form name="myForm" id="myForm">` since you are looking for the element with the id `myForm`